# Iterate to JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to iterate through a JSON object that doesnt have any key for the child arrays. I can access it by directly providing the key name but I want it to automatically extrapolate this and display the child elements of the arrays.

Here is the JSON:

```
 {
"Europe": {
"uk": {
  "name": "David Cameron",
  "images": [
    "http://imagetocameron.jpg",
    "http://imagetocameron2.jpg"
  ]
}, "france": { 
"name" : "Francois Hollande",
  },
}
```

This is what I have so far.

```
success: function (response) {
                var i = 0;
                $.each($.parseJSON(response), function (key, value) {
                    alert(response + firstProp);
                    $("#dataImages").append("<div>" + value.uk.name + "</div>");
                    i++
                })
            }
        });
```

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same `$.each()` method for that

```
success: function (response) {
    var i=0;
    $.each($.parseJSON(response), function() {
        $.each(this, function() {
            $("#dataImages").append("<div>" + this.name + "</div>");
            i++;
            $.each(this.images, function() {
                $("#dataImages").append("<div>" + this + "</div>");
            });
        });
    });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/BNSjX/14/)

Comment: That wouldn't work. images is a child of uk(country) not a child of europe

Comment: Works, but I UK is not the only object. I wanted it to get the data for each country. 

With this after UK it returns undefined.

Comment: are you want to iterate through all?

Comment: Yes exactly. Not just the UK

Yeah they do

Comment: That was just for this question. They all have name and images.

Comment: That would work but only for Europe. The original data has other countinents as well.